# Getting Error in Tomcat Maven Project "Can not find the tag library descriptor for "https://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"

Tags: maven, jsp, jstl, tomcat9

I created a simple Maven web project in Eclipse Version 2021-03 deployed to Tomcat 9 with the following pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.gillopez.web.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl-webapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>    
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>jstl-webapp</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I created a simple JSP that includes a taglib directive for the core JSTL tag:

```
<%@page import="java.time.LocalDateTime"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<html>
<body>

<c:set var="stuff" value="<%= LocalDateTime.now() %>" />

Time on server is ${stuff}
</body>
</html>
```

However, I see the following error message in the JSP editor:

```
Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
```

If I run it on the server, I get this error:
"The absolute uri: [http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application"

The JSTL packages are included in jakarta.jakartaee-web-api-8.0.0.jar:

[image]

Why am I getting this error message?

I can get it working by adding the following dependency in my pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Why do I need to do this if the JSTL packages are already included in the jakarta.jakartaee-web-api jar file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The artifact `jakarta.jakartaee-web-api` contains just the API jars of Jakarta EE 8, **not** the implementations. Since you used the `provided` scope, you assume that the container will provide the implementations.

However Tomcat is not a full Jakarta EE 8 server (such as WildFly) and it implements only five specifications (cf. [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html)): Servlet, JSP, EL, WebSocket and JASPIC. Therefore, for Tomcat 9, you should replace `jakarta.jakartaee-web-api` with:

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.4</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.6</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.el</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.el-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.3</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.websocket</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.websocket-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.security.auth.message</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.security.auth.message-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.3</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

All other APIs you want to use must be provided by your application together with their implementation.

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you very much!